# Composer->does not contain valid JSON

Tags: json, composer-php

Using: composer search 'tokens'command the IDE threw this error. I can't search neither download packages from: packagist.org

> C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat search fosuserbundle

```
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]                                        
  "http://packagist.org/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON        
  Parse error on line 1:                                                  
  <HTML><HEAD><meta h                                                     
  ^                                                                       
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['  



search [-N|--only-name] tokens1 ... [tokensN]
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the URL in a browser?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that the `packages.json` file on the server is good. 

`curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' http://packagist.org/packages.json`

Try again?

Comment: I'm using composer directly inside from PhpStorm, using the ComposerSetup deployed: composer.phar. Any related issue with proxy settings or some local's or company's firewall consideration?

Comment: Firts, I checked with 'SET' line from the command prompt if the env variables were initialized. Later I restarted. Now everything works just fine. All the troubles came by using my company's proxified connection.

Answer (score 0):

In windows machine, I've followed all these steps and get back in a correct behaviour (my problem was happening with `composer require`, but I believe it's the same as you described using `composer search` or if we would be using `composer install` for example. So, let´s see the steps:

1. Update composer (`composer self-update)
2. Disable IPV6 (as [pointed in official docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-), misconfigured IPV6 setting is a common source of issues)
3. Delete (or rename to repo_temp) your folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Composer\repo (in order to have all contents updated)
4. Delete (or rename to vendor_temp) your vendor folder inside your project (in order to force composer to download all components again, and [as pointed in this thread comment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3786#issuecomment-343646080))

After doing these steps, in my, case, the issue was gone!

Message before (ERROR):

```
> composer require ...
...

"https://packagist.org/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 1:
▼\\\\\\♥��ݎ♀���
^
Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

Message after doing the steps (OK)!:

```
> composer require ...

...

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```